# Pass variable to getSpanSize method on recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm stuck on pass variable in Java Android

I try with class getter and setter but no luck variable varA still no value inside getSpanSize.

I'm new with android java, so i try many possible way.

Is it possible to pass variable to getSpanSize? There is a better way to GetSpanSize?

> My Full Code (current) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String URL_DATA = "MY_URL";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private String test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    listItems = new ArrayList();
    loadRecyclerViewData();
}

private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
                        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            for(int j=0; j<o.getJSONArray("child").length(); j++){
                                if(j == 0) {
                                    ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                            o.getJSONArray("child").getJSONObject(j).getString("categories_name"),o.getString("name")
                                    );
                                    test = "header";
                                    listItems.add(item);


                                } else {
                                    ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                            o.getJSONArray("child").getJSONObject(j).getString("categories_name"),""
                                    );
                                    test = "item";
                                    listItems.add(item);

                                }
                                GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                                gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                                   @Override
                                    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                                        String test =test; 
                                       Log.d("TEST", test); **//this variable i want to be dynamic so span size will be depend on variable "test"**
                                        if(test == "header"){ 
                                            return 1;
                                        }else {
                                            return 2;
                                        }
                                    }

                                });


                            }
                        }
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: return type is `int`  you can't return a string, totally unclear  or probably `return 0;`

Comment: Plus: why would you want to define the value of the variable outside of the method?

Comment: How is this code even get compiled. Return type is `int` while the returned value is a `String`

Comment: Sorry, what i need is not a return value, but varA to be inside getSpanSize, for sectioned recyclerview purpose

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but I have nothing to say rather to ask you do it like below.
 1. Change your return type
 2. Better Set the variable inside your method(optional)

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public String getSpanSize(int position) {
       String varA = "aa";
        return varA; //this will return zero value, i need to be "aa" 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To access `varA` inside the overridden  `public int getSpanSize(int position)` method you need to declare it as `final`. However the return type is `int` so you cannot return `varA` because it is `String`.

```
final String varA = "aa";
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {

        Log.d("varA", varA); // you can do anything you want with varA here except to return it, because it is a String not an int
        return 0;
    }

});
```

**UPDATE**

Well you can assign your `test` dynamic variable to a final variable lets say `varA` and use `varA` inside the `getSpanSize` method:

```
final String varA = test;
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        Log.d("TEST", varA); //this variable i want to be dynamic so span size will be depend on variable "test"
        if(varA == "header"){
            return 1;
        }else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: variable varA will be change frequently, where is varA generated by loop. So isn't final string

Comment: So post your real code to get a real answer! I replied according to the code in your question where this variable can be declared final.

Comment: p.s. you can assign your "dynamic" value to a final variable, just show some code...

Comment: thank u for your concern, my code has been replace to full code.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can assign your `test` variable to a final one and use it in your `getSpanSize` method

Comment: "Test" variable succesfull pass to spanSizeLookup but only "item" value. Its Something wrong with position of GridLayoutManager ? or GridLayoutManager must declare in adapter?